# Can't connect to wss://api.poloniex.com

Tags: trading, poloniex

I try to connect to `wss://api.poloniex.com`

I'm using https://websocket.org/echo.html to test connection, but I got **ERROR: undefined**

What I'm doing wrong?

Are they have any updates or something?

Comment: Ok, they have new address: wss://api2.poloniex.com and they didn't update their docs.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154121/how-to-connect-to-poloniex-com-websocket-api-using-a-python-library